# How to change FontSize in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, font-size

I want to change the fontSize of the "Close" and "Open" texts. When i add this code:
`$content.style.fontSize="14px";` nothing works anymore. Without this code the javascript is working but the font size of the "Close" and "Open" are to big.
This is the code:

```
$(".head").click(function () {

$head= $(this);
$content = $head.next();
$content.slideToggle(500, function () {
    $head.text(function () {
        return $content.is(":visible") ? "Close" : "Open";
    });
});

});
```

Comment: $content[0].style.fontSize="14px"; should work..

Comment: I don't get why you pass a function to `.text`. Just pass the expression for that simple case.

Comment: C-link Nepal, thanks but not changing the font size.
MaxArt, coz i don't know it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$content` was a DOM node, then the way you are doing it would be fine. However, it appears to be a jQuery object, so you use [the `CSS` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead.

```
$content.css("font-size", "14px");
```

You also appear to be changing the CSS of `$content` but the text of `$head`, so you need to change the CSS for the element that contains the text you are trying to modify.

```
$head.css("font-size", "14px");
```

Comment: Still the "Close" and "Open" text is not changing with this code.

Comment: I added the `$content.css` and the `$head.css` still font size is not changing.

Comment: My mistake, was putting the `$head.css("font-size", "14px");` right after the `return $content.is(":visible") ? "Close" : "Open";`.
Thank you, works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know the result:

```
$content.css("font-size":"14px");
```